Spring integration + Micrometer: Context propagation is not working with DirectChannel
I'm trying to use the micrometer and instrumented the JPA repository and annotated it with @Observed.
I can see the traces & metrics around that but a new trace is generated with every method call from that JPA repository.
I tried using GlobalChannelInterceptor as follows but issue still persists -
@Bean
    @GlobalChannelInterceptor
    ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor observationPropagationChannelInterceptor(final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        log.info("Registering ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor with the registry {}", observationRegistry);
        return new ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor(observationRegistry);
    }

Here's how I define the DirectChannel -
    @Bean(name = CHANNEL_NAME)
    public MessageChannel myInputChannel() {
        DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        directChannel.setComponentName(CHANNEL);
        directChannel.setDatatypes(ConsumerRecord.class);
        return directChannel;
    }

Can someone please help in propagating the context properly in this such cases.

See Javadocs there in most recent version:
 * @deprecated since 6.1.7 for removal in 6.4 in favor of enabling observation on the channel and its consumer.
 */
@Deprecated(since = "6.1.7", forRemoval = true)
public class ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor extends ThreadStatePropagationChannelInterceptor<Observation> {

Either way the logic there is like this:
protected Observation obtainPropagatingContext(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    if (!DirectChannel.class.isAssignableFrom(AopUtils.getTargetClass(channel))) {
        return this.observationRegistry.getCurrentObservation();
    }
    return null;
}

The point is that there is no need to propagate context over DirectChannel since its subscribers are called on the called thread. If that thread has an observation, then it is going to be used in those subscribers.
You need to be sure that there is an observation where you send message to that myInputChannel. The point of the mentioned ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor is to propagate existing observation, not create one.

Thanks @Artem, Do I still need to use observationPropagationChannelInterceptor() with DirectChannel.

I've a sequence like this: KafkaConsumer -> MessageGateway -> springIntegrationFlow -> myInputChannel -> springService -> jpaRepository.
It'll be of great help if you could share an example of instrumenting this sequence.

No, you don't have to use ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor with DirectChannel. See my answer for details. It is void for those channels. In fact you don't have to use it at all according to its deprecation note.I cannot write the code for you for such a complex example. You need to provide some specific code in your question where you are struggling. But writing the whole application for your is something out of StackOverflow scope.

To avoid the confusion, I'm not asking you/anyone to write whole application. I was asking if there're any examples demonstrating that how a Spring integration flow can be instrumented.

Here is some to get some ideas: https://github.com/artembilan/microservices-patterns-spring-integration/tree/main/distributed-tracing
